# Why Compatibility mode only in IE not in other browsers?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

When i am checking my code with the `developer tools (F12)`, I have seen the option Compatibility view only in IE browsers. Why don't other browsers have this compatibility view mode?

I am confused about this. Can you guys clarify, is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: Did you read this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_mode ?

Comment: Because older versions of IE broke everything for developers. So to make things "easier", Microsoft decided to add a compatibility "feature" that (sometimes incorrectly) guesses when websites are intended for older versions of IE.

Comment: I'm curious: what do you think "compatibility mode" does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because IE is the only mainstream browser which was so screwed up in its rendering that developers had to specifically work around IE problems and deliver alternative versions of their pages just for IE. The "compatibility mode" switches between the newer standards compliant mode and the older screw-up mode.

Other browsers don't have it because they've never had an alternative screw-up mode.

Answer (score 0):

As for I know, IE mostly have compatibility issues with the older versions, That's why this option is provided by Microsoft. Moreover, very soon IE will be part of history as Microsoft is launching it all new web browser Microsoft Edge. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge